# How do I convert a decimal to string value for dollars and cents in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formatting, decimal

I am storing a cost in my application.  The cost is not formatted in the database. For example: 00.00 saves as 0, 1.00 saves as 1, and 40.50 saves as 40.5

I need to read these values from the database and convert them to strings for dollars and cents.  For example: 0  --> cost_dollars = "00" & cost_cents = "00", 1 --> cost_dollars = "01" & cost_cents = "00", 40.5 --> cost_dollars = "40" & cost_cents = "50".

Is there an easy way to do this in ruby on rails?  Or does someone have code that does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can accomplish that with this little bit of Ruby code:

```
fmt = "%05.2f" % cost
cost_dollars, cost_cents = fmt.split '.'
```

Comment: very useful, I was aware of sprintf but not of this plain use for "%".

Comment: In the format specifier (`%05.2f`), `0` means left pad with zeroes, `5` means use padding when the string is less than 5 characters (including the decimal point), `.2` means exactly two characters following the decimal point, `f` means floating point. [Full spec](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to format dollar values in a view, you should look at `number_to_currency` in ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper.

```
>> bd = BigDecimal.new "5.75"   
>> include ActionView::Helpers
>> number_to_currency(bd)
=> "$5.75"
```

As for breaking up the value into separate dollars and cents, my first question would be, "Why?" If you have a good reason, and you're dealing with decimals in your database, then you could do the following.

```
>> bd = BigDecimal.new "5.75"
>> "dollars:#{bd.truncate} cents:#{bd.modulo(1) * BigDecimal.new('100')}"
=> "dollars:5.0 cents:75.0"
```

Answer (score 7):

`number_to_currency` is nice, but it can get expensive; you might want to roll your own if you need to call it a lot.

You should be aware that using a float to store currency [can be problematic](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FloatingPointCurrency) ([and see](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/48754)) if you do a lot of calculations based on these values.  One solution is to use integers for currency and count cents.  This appears to be the approach used by the [money plugin](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/rails_money).  Another solution is to use a `decimal` type in your migration, which should work out-of-the-box for modern versions of Rails (> 1.2):

```
add_column :items, :price, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
```

(`:scale` is the number of places past the decimal, `:precision` is the total number of digits.)  This will get you [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/index.html) objects in Rails, which are a little harder to work with, but not too bad.

Both the integer and decimal approaches are a little slower than floating point.  I'm using floats for currency in some places, because I know I won't need to do calculations on the values within Rails, only store and display them.  But if you need accurate currency calculations, don't use floats.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of storing as a decimal, store as an integral number of cents. So 1 dollar is stored as `100` in the database.

Alternatively, if you don't mind a bit of performance overhead, check for '.' in the database's value. If it exists, split on '.', and parse the pieces as integers.

Answer (score 3):

sprintf is your friend here:

```
cost_dollars = sprintf('%02.f', cost)
cost_cents = sprintf('%.2f', cost)
```

Comment: This doesn't work; `cost_dollars` gets rounded (which isn't necessarily what you want), and `cost_cents` includes the dollars in addition to the cents.